# Problem Choice Grammar questions

Tags: gerunds

I have come across in exercise a sentence presented like this:

> I decide that **NOT GO/NOT GOING** would be the better decision.

Between NOT GO/NOT GOING I 've selected *Not go* but the right answer is 
*NOT GOING*.

Why is '**not going**' the correct answer?

Comment: You can't use infinitive as a subject. You can only use *noun, gerund* or *to-infinitve*

Comment: This is not a good exercise, this sentence is nonsensical, and *not to go* should be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting one!  "Not go" would be fine if you put it in quotes: *I decided that "not go" would be the better decision*.  The quotes remove the requirement that the whole thing be grammatical.

It would also be fine if you cast it as an infinitive: *I decided that not to go would be the better decision*.

Now, what makes "not go" ungrammatical without the quotes or the infinitive cast in that sentence is a bit more difficult to explain.  "Not go" *is* an infinitive phrase, but the "to" isn't present, so it's broken unless some other part of the sentence helps out, e.g., *I was scheduled to go to France on business, but the boss decided that I not go*.  The "that" makes up for the lack of the "to", as we see if we put in the now-superfluous "to":  *...decided that I not to go*.  But we can fix *that* by adding a "was" or "am" to soak up the "that":  *...decided that I am/was not to go".

Answer (score 0):

Let's rephrase your choices a little bit:

1. I decided that not go would be the better decision.
2. I decided that not going would be the better decision.

In #2, 'not going' is being used as a gerund. A gerund is a present participle (verb+ing) that functions much like a noun. Gerunds can be used as subjects or objects of phrases, clauses, and sentences. Many gerunds are common activities or hobbies.

- Surfing is officially a sport. Do you enjoy surfing?
- Soccer is also a sport. I like to watch soccer.
- Jogging is bad for your knees. Sugar is bad for your teeth.

In the sentences above, 'soccer' and 'sugar' are regular nouns while 'jogging' and 'surfing' are gerunds.

- I decided that surfing is more fun than soccer.
- I decided that soccer is more fun than surfing.

Here again, both 'surfing' and 'soccer' are [the subjects of a noun clause (sometimes called a verb complement](http://www2.gsu.edu/~eslhpb/grammar/lecture_13/that.html)). We [can also leave out the 'that'](http://web.ku.edu/~edit/that.html) without changing the meaning of the sentences:

- I decided surfing is more fun than soccer.
- I decided soccer is more fun than surfing.

*Decide* is a transitive verb--it must take an object. In other words, "I decided" is not a complete sentence.* You always decide something. Your sentence above could be rephrased as:

> I decided that not going was better than going.

Or

> I decided not going was better than going. (no *that*)

So of those two options, **not going** is the better choice.

And don't worry about the 'not'--it's just a negative gerund:

> I regret not wearing my coat today. It's too cold for short sleeves.

---

*Okay, technically, "I decided" is grammatical since there's a subject and a verb and the plurality matches. But it's an incomplete thought. What did you decide? We can't tell from that sentence alone. If it were part of a conversation that provided context, then it would be fine:

> Bob strode angrily into the room. He clutched a goblet in his left hand. "Who decided to buy the silver cups instead of the gold?" he demanded. His wife Sue rose calmly to her feet, looked him straight in the eye, and calmly stated, "*I decided.* Do you have a problem with that?"

We know from context that Sue decided to buy the silver cups instead of the gold cups. She decided buying the silver cups was the better choice. She decided not buying the gold cups was the better choice. She decided not to buy the gold cups.