# Can you correct some sentences for me?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, british-english

Find the mistake in each sentence then correct:

> 1. Every athlete dreams of taking part in the Olympics games.
> 2. Mike used to walk to school. Now I walked.
> 3. My uncle in which house we live, traveled abroad.
> 4. The world cup takes place each four years.

I have an exam the day after tomorrow, and what is needed is to underline the mistake then put in the  correct word.

Comment: A proof-reading question is off-topic. Please provide more information to your question, which part you think is incorrect, and why you think so.

Comment: @user178049 that's why I am here I need some one who can find the mistake then correct it.

Comment: It's a very lazy approach to ask strangers to do your homework. At least "attempt" to say where you think the errors might be. Then users can explain where you are wrong. Also, are you sure you copied No.2 correctly, I'm just checking to be absolutely sure.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes and It's from external educational book.

Comment: This is homework, you're supposed to be studying, you're the one who is taking an exam. You're the one who has to show they understand the task. Do you have absolutely no idea where the errors might lie? If that's the case, I'm sorry, but it looks like you're not going to pass the exam in two days' time. And there's little anyone can do. EDIT: OK, good to know the sentences have been copied correctly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA well I don't understand that  question. The book contains 9 units and 3 novel chapters and about 511 page,  and this is 4 question i couldn't solve out of hundreds and I have no one to teach me.

Comment: Are you sure Olympics was written in the test questions, because then there are two errors in Q 1.

Comment: Are you sure *The world cup* is written there. I think it's an error in punctuation, it should be *The World Cup*

Comment: To more closely follow the rules of this site, you should break this into 4 separate questions. In each one, you should state why you're having difficulty finding the mistake and maybe guess what the correction would be. Each of these sentences had different types of errors. It would help us give you better explanations if we could focus on each sentence by itself. Use this question as an example: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111887/problem-choice-grammar-questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Every athlete dreams of taking part in the **Olympic** games.

It should be **Olympic** without an s because that's an adjective form of the noun **Olympics**.

> Mike used to walk to school. Now I **do**.

Change **walked** to **do**. That's the only way I can think of to make it sound right.

> My uncle, in **whose** house we live, traveled abroad.

You need to use **whose** instead of **which** there because the house belongs to your uncle. **whose** is used when we're talking about possession and **which** when there are a number of options to choose from. And I think it also would be a very good idea to set that clause off with commas to make things look a little bit neater.

> The **World Cup** takes place **every** four years.

Change **each** to **every**. **each four years** just doesn't sound like correct usage to me. And **World Cup** should probably be all capital letters.

Comment: No. 2 is wrong.

Comment: Proof reading is off topic on this site. Can you imagine the flood of requests that would come if users began to feel sorry and answered people's homework.

Comment: No. 2 is still wrong, it's a very short sentence. Think about why  it is so short.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think there are two errors in each sentence. Even after CM's corrections, I still see things I would change.

Comment: @user47319 you seem overly confident that Cookie Monster has identified every error, he hasn't.

Comment: Yay, you got No. 2!

Comment: For No. 2, you can also change _walked_ to _walk_: _Mike used to walk to school. Now I **walk**_.